# Reshape stacked Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, reshape

I have the following DataFrame `df1`:

```
 df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(4,2), columns = {"var1", "var2"})
 df1["inst"] = ["A", "A", "B", "B"]
 df1.set_index("inst", inplace = True)
 df1 = df1.stack()

ipdb> df1
      inst
      A     var1    0.191094
            var2    0.100821
            var1    0.251331
            var2    0.528787
      B     var1    0.806549
            var2    0.638217
            var1    0.233541
            var2    0.905737
```

I would like to reshape the `df1` such that,

```
ipdb> df1
              A           B
      var1    0.191094    0.806549
      var2    0.100821    0.638217
      var1    0.251331    0.233541
      var2    0.528787    0.905737
```

I have tried to take the values of `df1` and reshape them using `reshape` function, but it has not worked:

```
ipdb> df1.values
      array([ 0.19109431,  0.10082081,  0.25133097,  0.52878702,  
              0.80654863,  0.63821703,  0.23354052,  0.90573699])

ipdb> df1.values.reshape(4,2)
      array([[ 0.19109431,  0.10082081],
             [ 0.25133097,  0.52878702],
             [ 0.80654863,  0.63821703],
             [ 0.23354052,  0.90573699]])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
values = np.transpose(df1.values.reshape(2, 4))
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=values, index=['var1', 'var2', 'var1', 'var2'], columns=['A', 'B'])
print(df2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) + [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) and reshape by [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) and [`stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html):

```
g = df1.groupby('inst').cumcount()
df1 = df1.set_index(["inst",g]).unstack(0).stack(0).reset_index(level=0, drop=True)
print (df1)
inst         A         B
var1  0.932293  0.214795
var2  0.503961  0.904046
var1  0.943864  0.232308
var2  0.398277  0.379333
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but an error is thrown: "ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape".